# loop through and print name of all excel charts vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to loop through all charts in a single sheet in my workbook and rename them starting at Chart 1, then Chart 2, etc....

There are 1000s of charts in the worksheet and I have to create PowerPoints with these charts - the charts are placed in specific slides and I need to reference the chart names in a particular order in the PowerPoint.  My current practice uses the below to generate a list of chart names but it is too slow (just wanted 2 days for the result and it was still working, so I killed it and need to explore other options.)

I think if I get a code that simply renames all the charts, I should be able to decipher a pattern and pull the appropriate chart numbers quickly.

So, once again, the needed result is a to list out all charts names on the "portfolio_charts" worksheet.  The output lists can be placed in column A starting in cell A1 of the portfolio_charts sheet if someone can help.

```
Sub list_charts_in_top_left_to_bottom_right()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, outputsh As Worksheet, last_cell As Range, oChartObj As Object
    
    'change Sheet4 to appropriate sheet name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("portfolio_charts")
    Set outputsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("portfolio_charts")
    Sheets("portfolio_charts").Activate
        
    
    outputsh.Range("A:A").ClearContents
    
    outputsh.Range("A1") = "Output:"
    
    If ws.ChartObjects.Count = 0 Then
        outputsh.Range("A2") = "No charts found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "Charts found: " & ws.ChartObjects.Count
    
    Set last_cell = ws.Range("A1")
    
    'find bounds of range by expanding last_cell with each chart
    For Each oChartObj In ws.ChartObjects
        With oChartObj

            If .TopLeftCell.Row > last_cell.Row Then Set last_cell = ws.Cells(.TopLeftCell.Row, last_cell.Column)
            If .TopLeftCell.Column > last_cell.Column Then Set last_cell = ws.Cells(last_cell.Row, .TopLeftCell.Column)
        End With
    Next
    
    Debug.Print "Bounds of range: $A$1:" & last_cell.Address

    Dim area_to_examine As Range

'For col = 405 To last_cell.Column Step 20 'start with column 5 (E) and then jump 21 columns at a time
    For col = 5 To 441 Step 20 'start with column 5 (E) and then jump 21 columns at a time
    
    Set area_to_examine = Range(Columns(col), Columns(col + 16))
    
    Debug.Print "Examining: " & area_to_examine.Address
    
        For Each rw In Intersect(area_to_examine, ws.Range("A1", last_cell.Address).Rows)
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                For Each oChartObj In ws.ChartObjects
                    With oChartObj
                        If .TopLeftCell.Row = cl.Row And .TopLeftCell.Column = cl.Column Then
                        outputsh.Cells(outputsh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = .Name
                        Debug.Print .Name
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I tried the above already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub list_charts_names()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, outputsh As Worksheet, last_cell As Range, oChartObj As Object
    
    'change Sheet4 to appropriate sheet name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("portfolio_charts")
    Set outputsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("portfolio_charts")
    Sheets("portfolio_charts").Activate
            
    outputsh.Range("A:A").ClearContents
  
    If ws.ChartObjects.Count = 0 Then
        outputsh.Range("A2") = "No charts found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Debug.Print "Charts found: " & ws.ChartObjects.Count

        For Each oChartObj In ws.ChartObjects
            With oChartObj
                outputsh.Cells(outputsh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = .Name
            End With
        Next
        
End Sub
```